# Excel VBA convert texts to numbers and dates

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that contains data downloaded directly from a database. It contains all texts including text-format dates and revenues. I want to convert 1 column from text to numbers, and 1 column of text (of dates) into dates format so that I can check for year and month to use `SUMIFS()` function.

[image: image here]

Additional information: as you can see from the attached image, in the Close Date column, the dates are all in 30.11.2016 format, connected with dots, and is in a **dd.mm.yyyy** expression but all in texts.

In the Amount column, the number of revenues are actually in a European expression, 50000,00 which actually means 50000.00, and 50000,00 is in text format.

Currently, I am using the `LEFT()`, `MID()`, `RIGHT()` functions to extract the strings of numbers of year, month, and day, and then DATE() function to convert to dates.

For the Amount column numbers, I am simply using TexttoColumns to do the manual work of conversion.

Is there a way to do these works in `VBA`? Can someone help me with the codes? I have some basic programming experience, but I have never exposed myself to `VBA` before.

Millions of THANKS! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Power Query for that. No coding required. Start a query and click the ribbon icons in the Query Editor to transform data, for example replace commas with dots, change type from text to number etc. Each action will be recorded as a step, using the M language. If desired, the M code can be manipulated, but for something this simple you don't need to.

The query can be refreshed when the source data changes.

Power Query is a free add-in from Microsoft for Excel 2010 and 2013 and it is built into Excel 2016 as Get & Transform.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use the Find and Replace function. Highlight the date column, find "." and replace with "/". Then that will give you some dates. You can do the same with "," and replace with "." - if it still appears as text, then you can convert to numbers from there. (in any case, VBA will be just harder work for you)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Exactly, I mean I could do it manually. But I was just wondering if there is a way to do it automatically using VBA. I am thinking that it would be great if every time we update the raw data table, these texts can be automatically changed into dates and numbers.

Comment: Yeah try the record macro function and record exactly what I just said, if you really want to do it via macro. You can then look at the code and see what it is doing. At high level it will be Select Range + ACTION (which is the find and replace function).

Comment: Hi gemmo, thanks a lot! I'll go try to work it out by recording Macro. Cheers!

Comment: If you have two screens, it's good to have the VBA editor in another screen while recording. Then you know exactly which action produced the code. And that way you can also start to identify which codes are unnecessary, and start deleting them afterwards. You will learn really fast by this method... and you start to see the same codes frequently. A lot of these people in the forum has forgotten what it is like to be a newbie.